# If I expand the EBS root storage of an windows instance, do I have to pay more?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get extra storage in my instance by expanding the EBS root volume. Will this cost me extra? and by how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will pay for the additional storage allocated. For example, if you expand a gp3 volume from 100GB to 150GB it represents an additional monthly cost of:

$0.08/GB-month * 50GB = $4

according to [current pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/).

It could vary depending on the type of volume or things like provisioned IOPS, snapshots, etc.